# Vulkan Dynamic Rendering vkCmdBeginRendering gives access violation exception

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am basically coding after Sascha Williams examples from github. I have checked that dynamic rendering extension is enabled. However at the line where `vkCmdBeginRendering` is called a access violation exception is thrown.

```
if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to begin recording command buffer!");
}

VkRenderingAttachmentInfo colorAttachment{};
colorAttachment.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDERING_ATTACHMENT_INFO_KHR;
colorAttachment.imageView = swapChainImageViews[imageIndex];
colorAttachment.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
colorAttachment.clearValue.color = { 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };

VkRenderingInfo renderingInfo{};
renderingInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDERING_INFO_KHR;
renderingInfo.renderArea = { 0, 0,swapChainExtent};
renderingInfo.layerCount = 1;
renderingInfo.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
renderingInfo.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachment;
renderingInfo.pDepthAttachment = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
renderingInfo.pStencilAttachment = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

vkCmdBeginRendering(commandBuffer, &renderingInfo);
std::cout << "wth";
vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);

VkViewport viewport{};
viewport.x = 0.0f;
viewport.y = 0.0f;
viewport.width = static_cast<float>(swapChainExtent.width);
viewport.height = static_cast<float>(swapChainExtent.height);
viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;
vkCmdSetViewport(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);

VkRect2D scissor{};
scissor.offset = { 0, 0 };
scissor.extent = swapChainExtent;
vkCmdSetScissor(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &scissor);

//VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = { vertexBuffer };
VkDeviceSize offsets[] = { 0,0 };
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, vertexBuffer, offsets);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffer, indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16);

//vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1,
//    &descriptorSets[currentFrame], 0, nullptr);

vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.triangles.size() * 3), 1, 0, 0, 0);

vkCmdEndRendering(commandBuffer);

if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
}
```

I also think I have set up my command buffers correctly

Comment: Is the feature actually supported on your device/driver version?

Comment: I think so. I have an RTX 4070ti, and I am on Vulkan SDK 1.3.250

Comment: `vkCmdBeginRendering` has to be dynamically loaded, are you sure it is a valid function pointer? What is the address that is causing the access violation? If the address is near 0 or 2^64 it would indicate a null pointer, if the address is very large, but less than 2^52  it would indicate a buffer overflow. If you try force stepping into `vkCmdBeginRendering` does it crash immediately, or are you taken into another function/assembly?

Comment: Hey, I think I solved the issue. It is because I have not requested the correct API version of Vulkan from setup.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the non-extension core version of the functions. `VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering` is core since 1.3, so you need to request at least that api version when you create the instance for your application. Unless you do that, the function pointers won't be loaded and you get the access violation because you try to call functions that don't have been assigned.

If you don't want or can support Vulkan 1.3, you need to use the extension versions of that functions that are suffixed with a KHR: `vkCmdBeginRenderingKHR` and `vkCmdEndRenderingKHR`. In that case you need to explicitly load these function pointers with the extension enabled using `vkGetDeviceProcAddr` or use a loader that does this for you.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I think this fixed it for me after requesting version 1.3 of the API. Before this, I was using version 1.0.